# Exceptions not being raised in C#. Just kicks out of the routine. Is this a bug?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I had an experience the other day where an exception should have been raised in my code, but instead it just kicked out of the routine and continued running (i.e. it's a WinForms project, so by "continued" I mean control just went back to the form where it waits for further user input).

I thought it was odd, but fixed the problem and didn't worry about it.  Today, I had the same thing happen in a different project where I had an XmlDocument object Load()'ing a file that didn't exist.  It should have raised an exception, but instead it just kicked out of the routine and gave control back to the form.

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour or know anything about what might be causing it, or does this sound like a bug in VS 2010?

Comment: I should note that when this happened, I did not have any exception handling (i.e. no try/catch's) in place anywhere in my code at all.

Comment: something to check, Clean Solution. Exit VS2010. ReOpen and the Recompile. I've seen some situations where the exceptions won't throw because the PDB gets locked by ProcessExplorer

Comment: Did you implement AppDomain.UnhandledExceptionEvent ?

Comment: @idstam Never even heard of it till now.

Comment: I'm getting this in WPF with a background process that I'm not handling properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same issue a will back. In my case, the problem only occur in development and not after the release. To get the errors, I found the you need to change a setting in VS. In the Debug menu, click on the Exception item. This tell when VS should break with error. You need to check the **Common Language Runtime Exception** Throw option. It should correct your problem. You will need to do this for each project.

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks on handled exceptions as well. It is a very ugly solution.

Comment: I know. I'm still looking for a better solution but I've yet to find one.